# asp.net Dropdownlist not refreshing after being removed

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, .net, webforms

I have a 2 drop down lists with company name and company addresses and a remove button linked to a stored procedure. Addresses is not being refreshed even though I am calling databind() on that address drop down List.  Can anyone point me out in the right direction?

```
//Button to remove Company
    protected void btnremovecompany_2(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ddlcompanyaddress2.SelectedIndex != 0) /*checked to see if an address is Selected first*/
        {
            string confirmValue = Request.Form["confirm_value"];
            if (confirmValue == "Yes")/* if yes is clicked then procedd to deactivate that company address*/
            {
                String strConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBConnection"].ConnectionString;
                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.CommandText = "usp_update_company_active";
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@companyname", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ddlcompany2.SelectedItem.Text.Trim();
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@address", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ddlcompanyaddress2.SelectedItem.Text.Trim();
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@category", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ddlTrades2.SelectedItem.Text.Trim();
                cmd.Connection = con;
                **ddlcompanyaddress2.DataBind();**
                try
                {
                    con.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw ex;
                }
                finally
                {   
                    /*Display message saying company is deactivated*/
                    string message = "Company  has been removed";
                    string script = "window.onload = function(){ alert('";
                    script += message;
                    script += "')};";
                    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "SuccessMessage", script, true);
                    con.Close();
                    con.Dispose();                        
                }                    
            }
            else
            {
                /*if canceled is clicked then display no changes*/
                this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('No Changes were made!')", true);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            string message = "Please pick an address first.";
            string script = "window.onload = function(){ alert('";
            script += message;
            script += "')};";
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "SuccessMessage", script, true);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Could be that your proc name suggests an update and not a delete,plus, you're binding the list before you execute the proc.

Comment: @DaveBecker so databind does not work on updates? I moved the databind() inside the try{} and it still does not work.

Comment: The storedproc removes the data from the database? What is the datasource of dropdown list ? Are you binding the dropdown list to datasource in page_load ?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya The stored procedure just sets the active column to 0.  The DDL is populated only for rows that active is =1. The datasource of the DDL is a column in the company table. No i am not binding it in page load I have 3 dynamic DDL. when the first one is selected the next one populates and then from the 2nd the 3rd populates( the address one that I want rebinded).

Comment: When you change any data in the database (marking row IsActive=0) will not affect to the datasource which is bound to the DDL as it is not connected anymore unless you are using SQL DataSource to populate DDLs. So what you need to do is rebind the DDL using the same logic as you bind it at the first time or on selection of other DDL.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Thank you for taking the time out to assist. I have figured out how to do it and will update my answer.

Comment: @TDang, yes `DataBind()` works with updates. I mentioned it because your question says you were deleting but the proc is named as an update, just making sure it is the right proc.

Answer (score 0):

You might be missing the datasource for your dropdown list. I am unable to find datasource in your code. You have just called databind method.
Can you please bind the datasource?

Answer (score 0):

added  this code to the try{} area and it resets all the dropdowns with fresh data.

```
ddlgettrades2();
getcompany2(ddlTrades2.SelectedItem.Text);
getaddress2(ddlcompany2.SelectedItem.Text);
```